# How to check the existence of D and E drives in WIX?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I want to install my application into E drive (E:\MyApp) if not exists then D drive (D:\MyApp), if D drive also doesn't exist in the target computer then I want to install in C drive (C:\MyApp). Which variable should I use in preproccessor to check drive existence ? Can anyone help me?

```
<?if E Drive exists ?> 
<?define varRootDrive = "E:\" ?> 
<?elseif  D Drive exists ?> 
<?define varRootDrive = "D:\" ?> 
<?else ?> 
<?define varRootDrive = "C:\" ?> 
<?endif ?> 
<?endif ?> 

<Property Id="TARGETDIR"> $(var.varRootDrive) </Property>
```

Comment: Poor netiquette. http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/How-to-check-the-existence-of-D-and-E-drives-in-WIX-td7583102.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor statements evaluate at build time not install time.  You will need a custom action to detect if valid drive letters exist and to set the installlocation dynamically at install time.

Comment: Thanks Chris! I have tried a similar scenario like below in my 64 bit dev machine, when I run the setup in the same machine, my install path is C:\MyApp , why is it behaving like this? 
 
                                                      
<?if $(var.Platform) = x64 ?>
<?define RootDrive1 = "D:\" ?>
<?else ?>
<?define RootDrive1 = "C:\" ?>
<?endif ?>
<Property Id='ROOTDRIVE' Value='$(var.RootDrive1)' />
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
<Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDERLOCATION" Name="MyApp">

Comment: 1) you didn't understand what I said about preprocessor statements and 2)  you are playing with fire if you are running your new installs on your dev machine.  Get a VM or you will get burned.